# Set timeout on idle for VPN (Cisco IPsec)?

Tags: vpn

Anyway to set a idle timeout on VPN? I want my VPN connection to drop automatically after idling for 5 minutes.

Using Lion 10.7.3 and built-in VPN Client (Cisco IPsec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it through the VPN connector.  This setting is determined by the administrator of Cisco/IPSEC VPN endpoint.

This not to say that you could not write a script that monitors network traffic and disconnects the client after a prescribed idle time - just that it is not available as a setting or attribute of the VPN connection on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences > Network. Select your VPN connection from the sidebar. Click on Advanced. In the first tab ("Options"), there should be the option "Disconnect if idle for X minutes".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That works for normal VPN, but when you choose Cisco IPSec, that option is not there :(